# Parcel doesn’t show image from js

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I’m using parcel for a practice project and I a number of items I want to use template literal to inject into the html but everything else is injected except the images.

This is the js snippet

```
let items = document.getElementById("bod");
let itemsData = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "apples",
    star1: "bi bi-star-fill",
    star2: "bi bi-star-fill",
    star3: "bi bi-star-fill",
    star4: "bi bi-star",
    star5: "bi bi-star",
    price: "25.99",
    img: "../../../static/images/berry2.jpg",
    alt:"apple",
}];

let generateItems = () => {
    return (items.innerHTML = itemsData.map((x) => {
        let { id, name, star1, star2, star3, star4, star5, price, img, alt } = x;

        return `
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="item my-2">
          <div id = product-id-${id} class="item-body text-center py-2">
            <div class="item-img">
                <img src= "${img}" alt= ${alt} class="image-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="item-des">
                <h3>${name}</h3>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class= "${star1}"></i>
                    <i class= "${star2}"></i>
                    <i class= "${star3}"></i>
                    <i class= "${star4}"></i>
                    <i class= "${star5}"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$ ${price}</p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn shop" >add to cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
        `
     }).join(""));
};

generateItems();
```